# Is it possible to pass the email of the user as a parameter to the login page of facebook?

Tags: php, facebook

I'm developing a simple facebook app, I already know the correct email of the user that will need to login into facebook, is it possible to pass the email to the login of facebook?

**[Like so](https://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=X&cancel_url=Y&display=page&fbconnect=1&next=Z&return_session=1&session_version=3&v=1.0&email=xyz@xyz.com)**

I'm just taking a wild guess here, I don't even know if it's possible to do this in any other way, so I'm asking you!

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.facebook.com/login.php?email=xyz%40xyz.com

where %40 is the hex code for the @ sign. Since '@' is an error control operator in php, changing it to hex causes it to pass through to the login dialog box.

Comment: I appreciate the effort of answering a question which is more than two years old. Tested, works. Accepted.